# Error thrown by a class method is not catched by a request handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

I created a transporter class to send emails:

```js
export class MailTransporter {
  receiver: string;
  private transporter: Transporter;

  constructor(receiver: string) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.transporter = this.getTransporter();
  }

  private getTransporter() {
    const { MAIL_USERNAME: user, MAIL_PASSWORD: pass, MAIL_HOST: host, MAIL_PORT: port } = process.env;

    if (!user || !pass || !host || port) {
      // NEXT LINE THROWS AN ERROR
      throw new Error('Specify MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD, MAIL_HOST and MAIL_PORT in .env');
    }

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host,
      port: Number(port),
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user,
        pass,
      },
    });

    return transporter;
  }

  public async sendMail(formValues: string) {
    const values: FormValues = JSON.parse(formValues);
    const message: SendMailOptions = {...};

    await this.transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      console.log('Email successfully sent. Info:\n', info);
    });
  }
}
```

And calling `sendMail` function from within `handler` function:

```js
export default async function Handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { body } = req;

  try {
    const response = await MessageTransporter.sendMail(body); //MessageTransporter is an instance of MailTransporter

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'OK' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not send the message' });
  }
}
```

But the error thrown in `MailTransporter` isn't being catched in `Handler`, instead I'm getting the error in my console [image]
And in my browser I'm getting 500 error on my POST request.

Could you please explain what's going on there? Why the error isn't catched inside `try catch` of `handler`?

Also, I'm kinda new to js classes so if you have anything to say about class design, please do.

Comment: That error gets thrown wherever the instance is _constructed_, which isn't in what you've shown.

Comment: The call to `getTransporter` is inside the constructor of `MailTransporter`, so you should be checking it at the invocation site where the instance is getting created for  `MessageTransporter`.

Comment: Ah, I'm invoking getTransporter on instance construction. Makes sense. Thank you guys.
@NalinRanjan I will accept your answer if you leave one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `getTransporter` is inside the constructor of `MailTransporter`, so you should be checking it at the invocation site where the instance of `MessageTransporter` is getting created.